# pycharm not providing all pyspark suggestion

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

I am using pycharm as IDE for pyspark development. I have added pyspark library as content root in my project in pycharm. But still it is not showing different methods that can be applied on pressing (ctrl + space)

e.g. in below code, read will return DataFrameReader object. Pycharm is providing methods applicable on sparkSession. However after read, I am not getting any suggestion of methods applicable on DataFrameReader like option, format, parquet etc.

```
sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv("sample.csv")
```

Do I have to do some extra setting in pycharm or is there any other better editor for pyspark development?